# Exception from hresult 0x8007007e ERROR for Port.dll in Spectrum Analyzer in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, spectrum

Heello

I want to implement spectrum analyzer in vb . I googled it and find an open source project. However it has Port.dll file . This is very old dll so this is not work in 64-bit machine.

Link: [Spectrum Analyzer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58148/Sound-Scanner-and-FFT-Analyzer)

Is there anybody know how to solve port.dll problem (or where to find new version port.dll) or any source codes for spectrum analyzer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. VS could not add the dll file to debug folder in project. After manually adding the dll into debug folder, this error is disappeared. Now , i have another problem ("A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack." . That is not relevant with this question. Anyway, the solution is that you have to copy manually dll into debug folder.

(Remark: Some people downvoted my question without giving any answers. I could not understand kind of those people.)